# Why is My HttpPost request being broken up into two requests?

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc, http-post

Just a little starter information.  I am writing an Andorid app that talks to a server written in C#.Net using the MVC platform.  Every request is a post and a ActionFilter attribute ensures that. However because of the issue .Net parses the HttpMethod as "ST".

The following is the code I use globally to make web requests from my application:

```
private String MakeRequest(String action, String params){       
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(mProtocol + mSubDomain + mHost + action);

        String args;
        if (params != null) {
            args = params;
        } else {
            args = "[]";
        }

        StringEntity requestEntity;
        requestEntity = new StringEntity(args);
        requestEntity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        requestEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        request.setEntity(requestEntity);   

    HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        String jString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);

        return jString;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I only have this problem with one particular method all other methods work just fine.

The following link is to a pcap file that contains the traffic so it is plainly visible. (I have filtered it down to only the applicable lines) 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/315661/defect.pcap

Comment: Also it may be worth mentioning that I've seen it work once out of maybe 20-30 tries. In the one time it succeeded the request was a single packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the use of 100-Continue in your POST? You typically don't need it as it only adds more overhead to your communication with the server - and it *can* cause issues if the service (or any piece of kit on the way between your device and the service, such as proxies etc.) you are posting to is not completely conformant.

```
HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false)
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver! Thank you so much, I wish I could up-vote this twice, I would have never figured that out on my own! :D

Comment: It's a really horrible feature to have enabled as default on a mobile device where the developer typically **knows** where the hell he is POSTing to - I think even `AndroidHttpClient` keeps it turned on by default.

Comment: I read that I should be using `AndroidHttpClient` but I believe I was having tons of issues with it, so I just went with the `DefaultHttpClient` which was working great up until now. :D

Comment: `AndroidHttpClient` comes with some of the basic settings you should be using - and also prevents you from doing stupid sh-t on the UI-thread - other than that it's pretty "meh".